# Residue Theorem and improper integrals

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, complex-integration, residue-calculus

Let $A$ and $B$ be Real parameters such that $A>0$ and $B>0$. How do I use the Residue Theorem to compute the following improper integral

$$\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{Ax\left(1-\frac{x}{B}\right)}\: ?$$

Is there another way to compute this integral without considering the Residue theorem?

PS: I've tried to solve it, and I find a null Principal value. However, I'm not quite sure if this is whether correct. In anycase, below one may see what I have found.

Let $C$ be a contour made up of two parts $C_{1}$ aline segment and $C_{2}$, a semicircular arch. Hence, we may rewrite the above integral as follows:

$\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty}\displaystyle\int_{C}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{Az\left(1-\frac{z}{B}\right)}=\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty}\left(\int^{R}_{-R}\frac{dx}{Ax\left(1-\frac{x}{B}\right)}+\int_{C_{2}}\frac{dx}{Ax\left(1-\frac{x}{B}\right)}\right)$

or
P.V.$\displaystyle\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{Ax\left(1-\frac{x}{B}\right)}+\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty}\int_{C_{2}}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{Ax\left(1-\frac{x}{B}\right)}$.

To compute the left-hand side of the previous equation, one needs to determine $ 
\displaystyle\oint_{C}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{Az\left(1-\frac{z}{B}\right)}$.

From the above, we see that there are two poles: one at $z=0$, and the second at $z=B$.

Therefore, from the Residue Theorem, we then have

$2\pi i Res\left(\displaystyle\frac{1}{Az\left(1-\frac{z}{B}\right)}, 0\right)= \frac{1}{A}$,
and

$2\pi i Res\left(\displaystyle\frac{1}{Az\left(1-\frac{z}{B}\right)}, B\right)= -\frac{1}{A}$,

which yields us to null Principal value.

Therefore,  are the above correct?

How do I to evalute the right-hand side integral $\displaystyle\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty}\int_{C_{2}}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{Ax\left(1-\frac{x}{B}\right)}$?

Comment: Please include your attempts.

Comment: Hi @vitamind d I have added my attempts,  enhanced the quality of my doubts, and stated the nature of the problem.

Comment: (+1) Now this is a good question.

Comment: I have put my post and only then have seen your approach. You are moving in the right direction - you should only add two small half-circles around $x=0$ and $x=B$ (to make a contour closed). If you "catch"  $x=0$ and $x=B$ inside your contour, you will also get two poles. You have shown that the residual in these poles are equal, with different sings - and the same story is with half-circles around $x=0$ and $x=B$. So, P.V. is equal to zero.

Comment: Integral along a big circle of radius $R$ can be estimated: $|I_R|=\frac{1}{AB}\int_0^{2\pi}|\frac{iRe^{i\phi}}{Re^{i\phi}(B-Re^{i\phi})}|d\phi$ $<\frac{1}{AB}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{\sqrt{B^2+R^2-2BRe^{i\phi}}}d\phi<\frac{2\pi}{AB}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(R-B)^2}}\to0$ as $R\to\infty$

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment

The integral $I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x(a-x)}=\frac{1}{a}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Bigl(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{a-x})dx$ taken in the infinite limits $(-\infty;\infty)$ is equal to zero.

To evaluate the integral in the P.V. sense you have to split integration into four parts (introducing big constant $M\to\infty$ and small $\epsilon\to0$:
$$I= \frac{1}{a}\biggl(\int_{-M}^{-\epsilon}\frac{dx}{x}+\int_{\epsilon}^{M}\frac{dx}{x}+\int^{a-\epsilon}_{-M}\frac{dx}{(a-x)}+\int^{M}_{a+\epsilon}\frac{dx}{(a-x)}\biggr)$$
$$=\frac{1}{a}\biggl(\log{\frac{-\epsilon}{-M}}+\log{\frac{M}{\epsilon}}-\log{\frac{\epsilon}{a+M}}-\log{\frac{a-M}{-\epsilon}}\biggr)=-\frac{1}{a}\log\frac{M+a}{M-a}$$
and then lead $\epsilon\to0$ and $M\to\infty$

You get $I\to-\log1=0$

If you want to use integration in the complex plane, you can close the contour adding a big half-cirlce, for example, in the upper half-plane (integration counter-clockwise), and also two small half-circles around $x=0$ and $x=a$ (integration in clockwise direction). There are no residuals inside the closed contour, and integral along big circle $\to0$ as $R\to\infty$, so the integral is equal to these integrals along small half-circles. But it is easy to show that they are equal to $\frac{-\pi i}{a}$ and $\frac{\pi i}{a}$ correspondingly, so their sum is equal to $0$.

Comment: Hi @Svyatoslav, I hope you are doing well. Thank you for the outstanding and clarifying insights of yours!

Comment: If I have understood it well, the integral that we have been discussing is zero. Therefore, if our goal relied on normalization, that wouldn't t be possible since A would diverge. Is that correct?

Comment: @ViniciusHolmes I do apologize for creating confusion. I will change the notation in my calculation to avoid mixing two parameters in my post.

Comment: Based on your wide experience, is there a non-standard way to determine a normalization constant of $$a\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{Ax\left(1-\frac{x}{B}\right)}$$  ?

Comment: @ViniciusHolmes I just changed the name of the constant in my post to avoid confusion. Please look. Constant A in your formula is just a constant, it does not affect the conclusion that P.V is equal zero.

Comment: Thanks.  I see that.  As I mentioned above, is there a non-standard way to compute the normalization of such integrals?

Comment: I'm afraid if the integral is zero we cannot normalize it - it will remain zero...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124147/discussion-between-vinicius-holmes-and-svyatoslav).